# Mysql Query: find the most checkout person on library?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table with the following items in

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `lib_transactions` (
  `transaction_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `person` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `action` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=205 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `lib_transactions`
--

INSERT INTO `lib_transactions` (`transaction_id`, `person`, `isbn`, `action`, `timestamp`) VALUES
(186, '1', '99-9263-544-4', 'check-out', 1483228800),
(187, '2', '99-9263-544-5', 'check-out', 1483229100),
(188, '1', '99-9263-544-4', 'check-in', 1483315200),
(189, '2', '99-9263-544-5', 'check-in', 1483661100),
(190, '3', '99-9263-544-4', 'check-out', 1483747500),
(191, '2', '99-9263-544-6', 'check-out', 1483833900),
(192, '2', '99-9263-544-6', 'check-in', 1483920300),
(193, '3', '99-9263-544-7', 'check-out', 1484006700),
(194, '3', '99-9263-544-8', 'check-out', 1484100300),
(195, '3', '99-9263-544-7', 'check-in', 1484453100),
(196, '3', '99-9263-544-8', 'check-in', 1484460300),
(197, '4', '99-9263-544-7', 'check-out', 1484553900),
(198, '4', '99-9263-544-8', 'check-out', 1484611500),
(199, '4', '99-9263-544-7', 'check-in', 1484705100),
(200, '4', '99-9263-543-8', 'check-in', 1484798700),
(201, '5', '99-9263-543-1', 'check-out', 1484798700),
(202, '5', '99-9263-544-2', 'check-out', 1484798700),
(203, '5', '99-9263-542-3', 'check-out', 1484798700),
(204, '5', '99-9263-541-4', 'check-out', 1484798700);
```

how can I achieve the following query :

**- which person currently has the largest number of books ?**

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: I feel like like we're covering similar ground to the last question

Comment: @jarlh mysql version 5

Comment: @Strawberry I did a mistake about that.

Comment: So you want to count checkouts - checkins, for each user?

Comment: @jarlh its  clear `- which person currently has the largest number of books ?`

Comment: A clear question has the expected result specified. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I don't understand your resistance to showing us what you've tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can group by person, get the count of checkouts minus the count of checkins (using `case when`), and order by that result in descending order. Then just keep the top 1 result:

```
select   person, 
         sum(case action when 'check-out' then 1 when 'check-in' then -1 else 0 end) checked_out
from     lib_transactions
group by person
order by checked_out desc
limit    1
```

With your sample data, person 5 is the winner with 4 books checked out.

Comment: where the check-in check-ut has engaged in this query?
this is not correct. please consider check-in checkout

Comment: I did not get that. Updated now.

Comment: Also you shouldn't be using `ORDER BY 2` SQL:1992 feature annymore it's is been official deprecated and does not exists annymore in i believe SQL:1999+ standards .. So MySQL might drop supporting  `ORDER BY 2` in the future.. Also it's error prone to use..

Comment: @RaymondNijland, point taken. Replaced with column alias.

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select lt.* from lib_transactions lt
where lt.action = 'check-out' and
  not exists (
    select 1 from lib_transactions
    where isbn = lt.isbn and action = 'check-in' and timestamp > lt.timestamp
  )
```

fetches all the rows for the books that have not been returned. 
So it needs `group by person` to give the result you want:

```
select lt.person, count(*) counter from lib_transactions lt
where lt.action = 'check-out'  and
  not exists (
    select 1 from lib_transactions
    where isbn = lt.isbn and action = 'check-in' and timestamp > lt.timestamp
  )
group by lt.person  
order by counter desc limit 1
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/iBvkqz9EjsWcDYp16oH96N/0).